# Lua iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, lua

I am trying to run some code from some time ago, after recompiling Lua for proper architecture, I am having some issues with the following line.

```
KillScript* script = (KillScript*)lua_tointeger(L, -1);
```

I am getting the following error on that line:

```
Cast of 'lua_integer' (aka'long') to 'KillScript' is disallowed with ARC.
```

Does anybody know why wouldn't this logic work?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

ARC -- automatic reference counting -- doesn't allow you to move between non-object reference types and object reference types.   A `lua_integer`is a C scalar.

You can do some unsafe casting dance to keep ARC enabled, but I suspect you'll run into other issues.

If it is a standalone project, turn off ARC and try compiling.  You'll likely run into other issues-- deprecation, etc... -- but at least you'll probably have relatively sane memory management behavior.

Comment: How can I do unsafe casting dance in this case?

Comment: @JohnAdams I don't remember, off the cuff.  I'd recommend against going down that path;  if it is sample code, turn off ARC and see if it works.  If it does, then figure out how to turn on ARC.  Sounds like old code.